# Android : the file exists and the path is correct but I got "No such file or directory"

Tags: java, android

On Android, I am having trouble to access to the file `/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output` (this file exists and the path is correct) with this code :

```java
String chaine = "";
try {
    File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String ligne;
    while((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
        chaine += ligne;
    }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

I specified the right to access to the internal memory in **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But I am still having this logcat error :

> 03-09 21:24:49.431 31186-31186/example.iris I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Is there a special way to access files on Android that I am not aware of ? I searched online and found `openFileInput()` but I got the same error. I tried a few things but I still got the same error and I am running out of idea...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are on Android 6 or above? Then add code to ask the user for runtimepermission. Or go to the settings of your app and switch storage on.

Comment: `(this file exists and the path is correct) `. You better check that in your code too with if (!file.exists()) { Toast.... return;}

Comment: I mean it exists because this file is created by the app earlier in the execution by `jniSvmPredict(predictPath + modelPath + "/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output");`. `jniSvmPredict` creates `iris.output` and writes the result of the prediction inside.

It's Android 5.1.1.

Comment: That is often enough to be shure that the file exists. So add the code i proposed please.

Comment: `predictPath + modelPath + "/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output"` ????? Welll and what would be that complete path? A non existing i would think. An impossible one.

Comment: The complete command is : `jniSvmPredict("predictFileHere modelFileHere ouputFileHere");` so I have : `jniSvmPredict("/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.predict /storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.model /storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output");` 3 files in the Download directory.

Comment: Check if the file exists before trying to open a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but it works with :

```
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/", "iris.output");
```

instead of

```
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/libsvm/iris.output");
```